# I have a hashset want to print only two objects without iterator or for loop. But i am getting error?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashset

how to check it

```
HashSet h=new HashSet();
h.add(123);
h.add(456);
h.add(789);
h.add(757);
h.add(989);
System.out.println( h.toArray(new String[2]));
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it My guess it is because of the raw type used

Comment: You are storing `Integer` values in your Set not `Strings`

Comment: http://ideone.com/2EESPp - a `String[]` array can not contain `Integer` objects. But even if you fix that (e.g. by using `new Integer[2]`), it still won't print only 2 (in fact it will print something odd like `[Ljava.lang.Integer;@106d69c` + the array that is returned contains all 5 elements), because you can't print just 2 without iterator or loop.

Comment: its not working even with String.

Comment: So ihave to use iterator or loop.

Comment: @VinayakDwivedi see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing Integer values in your Set not Strings

This should work for you:

```
HashSet<Integer> h=new HashSet<>();
h.add(123);
h.add(456);
h.add(789);
h.add(757);
h.add(989);
System.out.println((new LinkedList<T>(h)).subList(0, 2));
```

But the order in the HashSet is not defind.

Comment: @VinayakDwivedi If it helps, feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer

Comment: It internally uses iterator to print the list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be using *raw* types like this.  The `HashSet` class is a generic class, and you *should* specify what the typ parameter should be.

What you are doing in your example is putting integers into the hashset.  Therefore, you need to declare / initialize it as a `HashSet<Integer>` like this:

```
HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<>();
```

Then, you extract the contents to an array, you should do this:

```
Integer[] a = h.toArray(new Integer[h.size()]);
```

and look at the first two elements.

There is no API that will allow you to extract just the first two elements as an array, but you could achieve this by allocating an array by hand and iterating the set to pull out the "first" two elements.  (Noting of course that the order of the elements of a HashSet is *unspecified* ... so predicting which elements you will get is going to be difficult.)

---

You didn't say what error you experienced, but I expect it was an `ArrayStoreException`.  Your `HashSet` contains `Integer` objects and you cannot put an `Integer` into an array of `String`.